# RxSwift multiple subscriptions to one observable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I understand that if I want to have multiple subscriptions to one observable I need to use .share() operator, but I do not understand why exactly?

I looking for some example based on local data (not network) to demonstrate what is the difference between using .share() and without it.

What's the operator really do - using data from previous subscription or create new one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've written a small fictional example:

```
let shareObservable = Observable<Int>.create { observer in
    print("inside block")
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        observer.onCompleted()
    }
    return Disposables.create()
}.share()

shareObservable.subscribe()
shareObservable.subscribe()
```

with the following output:

```
inside block
```

If I remove `.share` from the `shareObservable` I will see:

```
inside block
inside block
```

The main point of this example is that I subscribe to the same `observable` the second time that is not completed yet and so the logic inside the block won't be executed.

*Let me know if you have some misunderstandings by now.*

[You can read more about `share`, `shareReplay`, `shareReplayLatesWhileConnected`, etc](https://medium.com/@_achou/rxswift-share-vs-replay-vs-sharereplay-bea99ac42168).